# ReferenceError can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ReferenceError: Can’t find variable: $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626455/referenceerror-cant-find-variable)

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: `$`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is the jquery javascript file loaded before you call anything with it -> using the selector $?
Please check with Chrome or Firefox+firebug if the jquery library is loaded correctly. Maybe the path could be not correct

After that, try to place your code into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

This will make sure that '// put all your jQuery goodness in here.' will be executed after jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: Well, OP accepted the answer, but how would it help a ReferenceError that can't find `$`? Your code *uses* `$` to set up the `.ready()`.

Comment: correct, I added extra info that the user first has to make sure jquery is loaded at all. So check if the path is correct.

Comment: Given that the `jQuery` library is properly loaded and that all the jQuery code is placed after the content (right before `</body>` tag) the document ready function is unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

wrong url in `<script>` for jQuery ?

Comment: he forget to link the jquery library :D

Comment: Yes, it should be point to jQuery not jQuery-UI