# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come across a fairly normal problem, but I can't solve it.
I tried to fix the jQuery scripts dozens of times, but it just won't work. It suddenly just stopped working after a few weeks.

I am positive that I included the jQuery script, and I did test if the site was alive.
However, [it seems like my browser or server ain't loading it with the site load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2R5G.png)...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2R5G.png]

It load my Google Analytics script perfectly fine, but it won't load the jQuery script. Even if I host i myself.

This is the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/ganalytics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
      $(this).data('jpg', $(this).attr('src'));
      $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('gif'));
    },
    function(){
      $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('jpg'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here, it produces the error on line #5 or [line #15 in my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPvtd.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPvtd.png]

I am lost here, how do I fix this? It was working great, and then suddenly, boom, out of nothing, it stopped working. Have been trying to fix this, but I can't figure it out.

Cheers, thanks for reading

EDIT: Included a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxGHM/3/) as it was requested in the comments. Hope I included the necessary  code.

Comment: What's the obfuscated thing you have in the screenshots? Is it a streetview image? ;)

Comment: Does it work if you move the `<script>` tag that loads jQuery inside the `<head>` section?

Comment: Yeah double check it is in the head and also you can run that first line easier with jquery 1.7+ by: `$(function(){ /*do work on page load*/ });` ... that is when you get jQuery working :P

Comment: PeeHaa: No, it's just my website, I just blur the URL as it is not ready yet for launch.
@staticsan: It is already in the <head> tag. Should I try the <body> tag?

Comment: @SpYk3HH: The script code worked wonder a week ago or so, it just seems I have trouble loading the jQuery. Isn't the <script> tag correct?

Comment: @ninjaboi21 "Isn't the <script> tag correct?" looks fine to me

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in an environment we can actually look at?

Comment: Like, for example, a JSFiddle? Because if I copy and paste the code you've given us there, it loads jQuery just fine.

Comment: I hope this will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/YxGHM/3/
The idea is: when the mouse is not hovered, display the dog or JPG. When the mouse is hovered, display the dancing boy or GIF. This worked great, till a few days ago.
EDIT: Not really sure about the `});//]]>`

Comment: @ninjaboi21: Your jsfiddle works fine if you delete the `<script>` tags from the JavaScript area. Tags are HTML, not JS.

Comment: Made the JSFiddle work now, but I am still unable to load the jQuery script on my website. Anything I could test?

Comment: Verify that it isn't the `$` reference by doing `console.log(window.jQuery)`. If that doesn't do it, then remove all other scripts including the analytics to see if that helps. If not, try a different CDN, like `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @am not i am: It just returns `undefined`, whether I use code.jquery.com or ajax.googleapis.com, it just doesn't load jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Replace all "$" with "jQuery". If that works:
[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)