# How would you change the height of a div based on the background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I am setting up pages to display the jpg's of comps that have been created and they all have a different height. Using javascript or jquery how would you auto adjust a div's height based on the height of the background image? The html would simply be laid out like so:

```
<body>
     <div id="comp"></div>
</body>
```

I realize you can set this is CSS but I want it to be dynamic and not have to add the height every single time. Thanks for any ideas at all.

Comment: I think its not possible to find the background image height or width using jquery

Comment: Here is a potential way of getting the background image height:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5106301/1028949

Comment: Is the div a child of the background image?

Comment: I have done some research. There are ways to find the height/width of an image but nothing about taking those dimensions and auto adjusting a div's height.

Comment: MrSlayer - I did check that out but after determining the size how would you "attach" those dimension to the div sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this (untested) code will help you see how it can be done:

```
// taken from the link in my comment to OP
var url = $('body').css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace("'", '').replace('"', '');
var bgImg = $('<img />');
bgImg.hide();
bgImg.attr('src', url);
bgImg.bind('load', function()
{
    var height = $(this).height();
    $('#comp').height( height );
});
```

Comment: I tried out this suggestion but it's returning this error "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $"

Comment: [Look around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888725/jquery-referenceerror-cant-find-variable) for answers to help you understand why that error is coming up