# Ajax, PHP and MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem with Ajax. Nothing happen when I change my select value.

I have a div with the id textHint in order to print the result.

Here is my select :

```
<form>              
    <select id="choix" name="choix" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <div class="tutorial_list">
            <?php 
                $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); 
                mysql_select_db('Projet',$db); 

                $sql = 'select NomPromo, NumPromo from Promo';
                $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

                while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
                     echo'<option value="'.$data['NumPromo'].'">'.$data['NomPromo'].'</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here's my script :

```
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
           return;
           } else { 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","data.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here's my data.php :

```
<?php 

    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); 
    mysql_select_db('Projet',$db);

    $sql = "select Nom, Prenom from User where Groupe ='".$q."'";
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
         echo $data['Nom'].' '.$data['Prenom'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and removed entirely in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) if you can. 
You should choose another API, like `mysqli_*` or PDO instead - see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Check whether `showUser` method is getting invoked or not on changing value in selectbox

Comment: Oh yes I will change that when this things work. I'll use mysqli

Comment: Does it generate any errors? In PHP, check the error_log ([`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), 
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)) or in JavaScript (see Console in your browser).

Comment: There is an error : `[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText')
 onreadystatechange` on the line `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what `<div class='tutorial_list'></div>` doing inside `<select></select>`

This **error**

> [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ (fonction
>   anonyme)prof.php:75

may be because of few reasons. a) jquery library is not loaded correctly b) path could be not correct. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888725/referenceerror-cant-find-variable)

I've done little changes, you can try this out.

```
<form>              
  <select id="choix" name="choix">
    <div class="tutorial_list">
      <?php 
      $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); 
      mysql_select_db('Projet',$db); 

      $sql = 'select NomPromo, NumPromo from Promo';
      $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());

      while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
           echo'<option value="'.$data['NumPromo'].'">'.$data['NomPromo'].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
    </div>
  </select>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#choix').change(function(){
      var q= $('#choix').val();
      $.ajax({url:"data.php?q="+q,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $('#txtHint').html(result);
      }});
    });
  });
</script>
```

[**NOTE**: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`]

Comment: It don't works there is the error `$('#choix').change(function(){` he can't find the variable $

Comment: "[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
 (fonction anonyme)prof.php:75"

Comment: On the following line `$('#choix').change(function(){`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please go through it @FlorianSL

Comment: I've put this at the top <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and the document ready function but nothing happen when I change the value

Comment: and the div tutorial_list is useless i've deleted this. And the path to data.php is correct

Comment: I have used all your code. Nothing happen, and no errors... When I change the value it load data.php but print nothing

Comment: Can you do one thing for me. For a time being in **data.php** page. Remove all code. and just `<?php echo "asd";?>` and see what happens. You are close to it. @FlorianSL

Comment: Nothing happen.. Thank for your help. I really don't know why it don't work. When i use the developper tool on safari I can see that when i change the value it load data.php

Comment: My data.php need to return value? Or he just can print the result? @Nana

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102255/discussion-between-floriansl-and-nana-partykar).

Comment: When i go in the development tool and I press on data.php, it tells me that there is the value that I want to print. So my data.php works, there is an error for print this