# Prompt function inside a jQuery object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Excuse me if I say something stupid here, I'm a bit of a noob at jQuery. I was working on a button in HTML/jQuery that is supposed to trigger a prompt when it was clicked, and then return another number. The problem is that the prompt doesn't trigger when I click on the button.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Progress-Button').click(function() {
        var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
        if (isNaN(Number(question)) === false) {
            var width = question * 10;
            return width;
        } else {
          question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked.", "Enter here");
        }
    )
})
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</html>
<head>
<title>Ian TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="Progress-BG"></div>
    <div id="Progress-Bar"></div>
    <button id="Progress-Button">Click Me</button>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any error logged ?

Comment: I haven't checked. I'll do that now

Comment: It gives a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`. I included the CDN from google for jQuery.

Comment: You did not include `jquery` in your page .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError can't find variable: $](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888725/referenceerror-cant-find-variable)

Comment: You're missing a `}` to close your callback function inside of your `click` method call. Your issue is probably just due to this typo. I would expect you to be seeing an error like: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Comment: I added the rest of my HTML.

Comment: You have wrong in your html implementation

Comment: Ok, so I just check the file path for the CDN, and it shows up in Resources but still gives the reference error. I also fixed the typo, still nothing.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! I was using an outdated version of jQuery! TY everyone!

Comment: Or not. still having the issue for some reason. I'm on Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `else` block is missing a curly brace, and some semicolons are missing as well.  Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Progress-Button').click(function() {
    var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
    if (isNaN(Number(question)) === false) {
      var width = question * 10;
      alert(width);
      return width;
    } else {
      question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked.", "Enter here");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="Progress-BG"></div>
    <div id="Progress-Bar"></div>
    <button id="Progress-Button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running smoothly, the only problem is you did not properly closed after the else

> });

Try your code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Progress-Button').click(function() {
    var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
    if (isNaN(Number(question)) === false) {
      var width = question * 10;
      return width;
    } else {
      question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked.", "Enter here");
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some errors in your HTML, which are likely contributing to this. The `<script>`, `<meta>`, and `<link>` elements should be inside of `<head>`. Both `<head>` and `<body>` should be within `<html>`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ian TEST</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="Progress-BG"></div>
            <div id="Progress-Bar"></div>
            <button id="Progress-Button">Click Me</button>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some more details on the structure of an HTML document, have a look at this [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.1).

Answer (score -4):

You should use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   enter code here
```

Not this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
enter code here
```

...